# Insert() node method in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a LinkedList that I have created when used creates a Band, Song, and Duration of the song list.

Example output:

Band: Led Zepplen |  Song: Stairway to Heaven |  Duration: 8.02 minutes
Band: AC/DC |  Song: Back in Black |  Duration: 4.14 minutes
Band: The Rolling Stones |  Song: Paint it Black |  Duration: 3.46 minutes

What I can't figure out is how to implement a method where I can insert a node in any given position.  So far my code looks like this:

```
public class Song {
    private String band;
    private String name;
    private double duration;
    Song next;
    
    public Song(String band, String name, double duration) {
        this.band = band;
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getBand() {
        return band;
    }

    public void setBand(String band) {
        this.band = band;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(double duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Song getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Song next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    
    public Song getLastNode() {
        Song currentNode = this;
        while(currentNode.next != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        };
        return currentNode;
    }
        
    public void append(Song newSong) {
        Song tmpNode = this.getLastNode();
        tmpNode.next = newSong;
    }
    
    public void printAllSongs() {
        // print all songs from j
        Song currentNode = this;
        do {
            System.out.println("Band: " + currentNode.getBand() + " | " +  
                                " Song: " + currentNode.getName() +  " | " + 
                                " Duration: " + currentNode.getDuration() + " minutes");
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        } while( currentNode != null );
    
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Song mySong = new Song("Led Zepplen", "Stairway to Heaven", 8.02);
        mySong.append(new Song ("AC/DC", "Back in Black", 4.14 ));
        mySong.append(new Song("The Rolling Stones", "Paint it Black", 3.46));
        
        mySong.printAllSongs();

    }

}
```

What is one way I could achieve coding a method that inserts a node at any given position?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but this is a common error — a `Song` should not have a `next`. When you have a linked-list, each element has a `next` and should have a `value` -- in your case the value is a Song object; so it is the list `Node` object that should have a _value_ and a _next_ (otherwise any sort of object you might ever want to put in a list must have a "next")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void insertAt(int index, Song song) {
    // First, check the inputs
    if (index > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if (song == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    
    // Skip (index - 1) songs from the beginning (this), keeping track of previous entry
    Song cur = this, prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur.next;
    }

    // Insert in between previous and current entry
    if (prev != null)
        prev.next = song;

    song.next = cur;
    ++size;
}
```

A good visualisation can be found at [VisuAlgo](https://visualgo.net/en/list)

Comment: Thank you for the VisuAlgo link, it's awesome and helps me visualize things.
Could you however explain your solution please?  It hasn't been working for me and I keep getting errors.

Comment: @Dasax121 I forgot to mention that it is convenient to store the number of songs in the list, so you need to add a new field, `private int size = 1`, to the class, and increment it whenever you add a new element, like in this method and in `append`.

Comment: @Dasax121 Also, this code won't work whe index = 0, since we treat `this` as the beginning of the list. There is two solutions: make `insertAt` return the beginning of the list, and when `index == 0`, return `song`, otherwise return `this`. This is, apparently, not very convenient. The better way would be using a wrapper class for the list, i.e. `Album`, and keep a sentinel element (an empty `Song`) as the starting element, so actual elements of the list would go after that, and inserting an element at the beginning would be no different from any other position.

Comment: @Dasax121 Although, the traversal must be modified accordingly, as in going to the `next` in the first line of the loop, to skip the sentinel.